# Method is not defined - callObserverMethod

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, theme

After a forced server update to php5.5 we have been faced with this error below:

```
Method "addLibrary" is not defined in "Meigee_ThemeOptions_Controller_Observer"

#0 /home/user/website.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1340): Mage::throwException('Method "addLibr...')
#1 /home/user/website.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Meigee_ThemeOptions_Controller_Observer), 'addLibrary', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#2 /home/user/website.com/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#3 /home/user/website.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(351): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#4 /home/user/website.com/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#5 /home/user/website.com/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#6 /home/user/website.com/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#7 /home/user/website.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#8 /home/user/website.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#9 /home/user/website.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /home/user/website.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /home/user/website.com/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home/user/website.com/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

Obviously it is a theme issue, but what should I be looking at to fix it?

EDIT: In response to the below answer, I can't access admin section either, I get the same error. Here is the relevant config.xml file in case that helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Meigee_ThemeOptions>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <depends>
            <!-- no dependencies -->
            </depends>
        </Meigee_ThemeOptions>
    </modules> 
    <global>
        <models>
            <!-- ... -->
            <ThemeOptions>
                <class>Meigee_ThemeOptions_Model</class>
            </ThemeOptions>   
            <!-- ... -->
        </models>
        <events>
          <adminhtml_controller_action_predispatch_start>
            <observers>
              <Meigee_ThemeOptions_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <!-- inchooadminthemecontroller/observer  -->
                <class>Meigee_ThemeOptions_Controller_Observer</class>
                <method>overrideTheme</method>
              </Meigee_ThemeOptions_observer>
            </observers>
          </adminhtml_controller_action_predispatch_start>  
        <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
            <observers>
                <ibanner_layout_generate_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Meigee_ThemeOptions_Controller_Observer</class>
                    <method>addLibrary</method>
                </ibanner_layout_generate_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>    
        </events>
        <helpers>
            <ThemeOptions>
                <class>Meigee_ThemeOptions_Helper</class>
            </ThemeOptions>
        </helpers>
        <extraconfig />
        <blocks>
            <meigee_themeoptions>
                    <class>Meigee_ThemeOptions_Block</class>
            </meigee_themeoptions>
            <meigee_general><class>Meigee_ThemeOptions_Block</class></meigee_general>
            <meigee_productpage><class>Meigee_ThemeOptions_Block</class></meigee_productpage>
            <meigee_sidebar><class>Meigee_ThemeOptions_Block</class></meigee_sidebar>
            <themeoptions>
                    <class>Meigee_ThemeOptions_Block</class>
                    <rewrite>
                        <bestsellers>Meigee_ThemeOptions_Block_Bestsellers</bestsellers>
                    </rewrite>
            </themeoptions>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <!---->
    <default>
        <meigee_general>
            <appearance>
                <font>0</font>
                <default_sizes>1</default_sizes>
                <fontsize>14</fontsize>             
                <lineheight>24</lineheight>
                <fontweight>400</fontweight>
                <patern>pandora</patern>
            </appearance>
            <layout>
                <sidebar>sidebar_right</sidebar>
                <grid>grid_standard</grid>
                <cartpage>cart_accordion</cartpage>
            </layout>
            <menu>
                <type>menu_wide</type>
                <home>1</home>
            </menu>
            <otheroptions>
                <totop>1</totop>
                <labelnew>1</labelnew>
            </otheroptions>
            <lang_switcher>
                <status>language_select</status>
                <label>0</label>
            </lang_switcher>
            <curr_switcher>
                <status>currency_images</status>
                <label>0</label>
            </curr_switcher>
            <fancybox>
                <fancybox_status>1</fancybox_status>
                <fancybox_home>1</fancybox_home>
                <fancybox_listing>1</fancybox_listing>
            </fancybox>
        </meigee_general>
        <meigee_productpage>
            <productpage>
                <prevnext>prevnext</prevnext>
                <moreviews>moreviews_slider</moreviews>
                <collateral>collateral_tabs</collateral>
                <collateral_related>related_slider</collateral_related>
            </productpage>
        </meigee_productpage>
        <meigee_sidebar>
            <block_categories>
                <status>1</status>
                <option>1</option>
                <option_2>1</option_2>
            </block_categories>
            <block_shop_by>
                <status>1</status>
                <option>1</option>
                <option_2>1</option_2>
            </block_shop_by>
            <block_compare>
                <status>1</status>
            </block_compare>
            <block_compared>
                <status>1</status>
            </block_compared>
            <block_viewed>
                <status>1</status>
            </block_viewed>
            <block_wishlist>
                <status>1</status>
                <option>1</option>
            </block_wishlist>
            <block_tags>
                <status>1</status>
            </block_tags>
            <block_orders>
                <status>1</status>
            </block_orders>         
        </meigee_sidebar>
    </default>
</config>
```

EDIT 2: Tried disabling the module by the Meigee_ThemeOptions.xml file, still getting the same error:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
      <Meigee_ThemeOptions>
         <active>false</active>
         <codePool>local</codePool>
      </Meigee_ThemeOptions>   
   </modules>
</config>
```

EDIT 3: Developer mode *should* be off. The index.php file has the below lines:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
}
else
{
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(false);
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
}
```

And .htaccess file has the line `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "false"`

I added the line to htaccess file because I *did* turn on developer mode (by commenting out the if statement) to get some error logs but don't think it has turned off correctly...Any help with that would be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, you only get this error when you have developer mode enabled, otherwise the missing method is simply ignored. Are we talking about a production server? Are you sure you want to have developer mode on there?

Comment: See edit above, don't know how to turn off developer mode correctly.

Comment: Simply remove the line from the .htaccess or comment it out with `#`, since Magento is checking if the env variable **is set**, not if it's true or false. That should turn off dev mode.

Comment: I only added that line because it wasn't working, but removing that line has worked now. If you add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Good to hear! I hope this solves your problem though, since the problem with the missing observer method still remains. Did you check if there's a class `Meigee_ThemeOptions_Controller_Observer` declared somewhere? What is its file path?

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to begin looking, but the config.xml above has it declared? The file path for that file is `/app/code/local/Meigee/ThemeOptions/etc`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39200/discussion-between-fmrng-and-anothershrubery).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is only displayed when you have developer mode on. Leaving developer mode on a production server is really not recommended, since you run the risk of exposing your shop structure and could possibly lead to vulnerabilities, attacks, etc. Make sure you turn developer mode off by making sure the environment variable `MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE` is not set.

Please notice: **not set** means that the variable is not declared, since Magento is checking for its presence, not whethere it's `true` or `false` or any value.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like if you have an event observer defined - I guess in one of the 3rd-party-modules. It looks like there is empty method registered for the event.

Please check observer listening on event in extension's **config.xml**. Try disabling the module and check again.

Comment: Why would this change just because of the php version upgrade? It says this is to do with the Meigee Theme, not really an extension? Where would the confg.xml file be? What would I do with it? I can't get into the admin area, same error, so how do I disable the module? Don't want to turn off the them as it defines how the site looks.

Comment: See above edit for config.xml file.

Comment: you can disable theme extension directly from file without login in admin

Comment: Can you expand on how I can do that? Will it affect the functionality/look of the site?

Comment: go to **app/etc/modules/Meigee_ThemeOptions.xml** and change true to false. Save it and check on frontend. Yes, it will disable extension functionality. You can reupload that extension code. I had same issue and I fixed by this way.

Comment: I've disabled the module as you've described but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: See edit above again for Meigee_ThemeOptions.xml file.

Comment: Can you post code of index.php here

Comment: This was an issue with developer mode being on (see accepted answer). There may be an issue with this missing function but it would have been a constant issue for the past 2 years with no affect on the store, so I have gotten the store to display and will ignore the hidden error. Thanks for your help.